# How to add a hightlight for eyeball?

Tags: rendering

I use Toonshader to render my character.
[image]
I want to add a light for the eyeballs.
[image]
This is my node setup.

Comment: Could you please send over your .blend file? (use pasteall or blend-exchange)

Comment: You said "I want to add a light/highlight for the eyeballs", yet I see a light reflected in the eyeballs.  You might want to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: @james_t I think that is painted on after the fact

Answer (score 2):

Map your specular highlight to a Black & White ColorRamp. Plug that into the top socket of a Color Mix node with the blending mode set to SCREEN or ADD. Plug your eye texture color noodle into the bottom socket.

ADD/SCREEN basically makes whatever is black transparent and whatever is white stays opaque. Changing the white color in the gradient to a gray color will make that color partially transparent.

Edit the rotation on the Mapping node before the glossy BSDF to move the highlight around.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I might add, that taking the time to learn about "Blending Modes" is extremely helpful for lots of things. It's a universal concept in graphics programs and I find myself using them constantly. Especially "Multiply" which makes white transparent, and "Add/Screen" which makes black transparent.